# Retrieving cookie in the same page

Tags: html, jsp, cookies, submit

I have index.jsp page in which I have two input fields for two numbers to perform calculation. I have 4 buttons for ADD,SUBTRACT,MULTIPLY and DIVIDE. When I click on ADD button, it will go to servlet named Calculate.java and calculate the result and set the cookies. Now when I open index page, I want to display history of all previous calculations in index.jsp using cookies already set.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use of cookies is a bad idea instead use encodeUrl().reason being not all browser supports cookies meaning if the user has blocked cookies then your code will not work.But in case of encodeUrl() no problem will arise even if the browser has disabled cookies